# Penalty for an objective function to encourage "pigeon-holing"?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have an objective function $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ that I'm trying to optimise. Simultaneously, I have $n$ given "target points" $y_1, \ldots, y_n$. Ultimately, I want each of the $x_i$'s to gravitate towards a **different** target point, so that each target point "has a single pigeon in its hole". What penalty can I add on to the function to encourage this? All I can think of is something like
$$\text{penalty}=\sum_i \left(\text{softmin}_j \left|y_i - x_j\right|\right)^2$$
For the record,
$$\text{softmin}_j ~ a_j = - \text{logsumexp}\left(-a_1, \ldots, -a_n\right)$$
but one could use [anything similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum).
The absolute value is to encourage $\text{softmin}_j$ to prioritize a single $x_j$ corresponding to a $y_i$, and the squaring+sum is to encourage the each $y_i$ to do a good job of picking at least one $x_j$.

Comment: If the $x$ and $y$ are in one-to-one correspondence, can't you just penalise the $x$s being too close to each other?

Comment: @ZoeAllen that might be part of the answer. But actually encouraging the $x$'s to go to the $y$'s is also part of it. And also, I'm not sure the best way to penalize the $x$'s being close together. Something that's established as working decently well in this regard would be appreciated.